# app deployed to Kubernetes but it is not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, continuous-integration, gitlab, amazon-eks

i'm working with aws eks (Kubernestes cluster) to deploy an application from gitlab to the an aws cluster. When i deploy the app to the cluster i see some services with command `kubectl get service --all-namespaces` und i get laodbalancer but i can not access to the app. The application called csa-17887811-production (see Screenshot). I think i have to add it to the Pods. when i type  `kubectl get pods` i see only the Hello world application called "web". Could you please show me, how can i access the app from the web browser throw the Loadbalancer.

Note: when i navigate with the loadbalancer link i get this response :  `default backend - 404`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cj3Xx.png)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to expose the app via nginx ingress. For that you need to create a ClusterIP [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) and an [ingress resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /testpath
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

A pictorial representation of how you can access pods using ingress and load balancer on AWS.

[image: ingress architecture]

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/network-load-balancer-nginx-ingress-controller-eks/

Comment: Thank your for response. Yes ingress has been installed as an application in gitlab but not locally, still possible to expose it and access it throw the loadbalancer link?

Comment: you don't need to create anything locally...nginx ingress controller need to be installed on Kubernetes which I think already done as per the screenshot..I don't see the service and ingress which you need to create

Comment: i want to access to this application csa-17887811-production (see screnntshot) but it doesn't exit in the Pods list. According to the gitlab documentation the Auto Devops service from Gitlab did everthing from build, test to the deployement

Comment: it's there in a different namespace..not in default namespace

Comment: why it doesn't shown when i type `kubectl get pods` ? kann you please show me how can i navigate to the application.

Comment: run kubectl get ns to see all namespacename in the cluster and then for each of those namespaces run kubectll get pods -n namespacename

Comment: kubectl get ns
NAME                      STATUS   AGE
csa-17887811-production   Active   3h43m
default                   Active   4h12m
gitlab-managed-apps       Active   4h2m
kube-node-lease           Active   4h12m
kube-public               Active   4h12m
kube-system               Active   4h12m
#########kubectl get pods -n csa-17887811-production
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
production-5b48dffcb4-4kwwl           1/1     Running   0          3h43m
production-postgres-bbbfbb5f6-jww2z   1/1     Running   0          3h43m

Comment: sorry for the comment i can not post a screenshot here but it stills visible only "web" namespace when i type `kubectl get pods`

Comment: kubectl get pods will show pods in default namespace only unless you pass a namespacename as parameter...pls add output not screenshot in the question not in comments for better readability

Comment: sorry about it und thank your for your support it still not working maybe it's a netwok configuration issue. i don't have enough knowledge to work with Kubernetes and devops.